# NodeJS server, res.sendfile returning HTML but not the "jscript includes" (<script src>)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Basically I want to make a server and then a simple javascript site with phaser to try some stuff, but the html stuff shows, but not the javascript.

Here are my different files & codes:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<center>
 <body>
 test
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <div id='game'></div>
  </body>
</center>
</html>
```

game.js:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
    game.load.image('char', 'char.png');
}

var sprite;
var cursors;

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    game.physics.p2.defaultRestitution = 0.8;
    sprite = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'char');
    game.physics.p2.enable(sprite);
    sprite.body.setZeroDamping();
    sprite.body.fixedRotation = true;
    text = game.add.text(20, 20, 'l2arrowkeys', { fill: '#ffffff' });
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {

sprite.body.setZeroVelocity();

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveLeft(200);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveRight(200);
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveUp(200);
    }
    else if (cursors.down.isDown)
    {
     sprite.body.moveDown(200);
    }

}
```

server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('a user disconnected');
    });
});
http.listen(1337, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:1337');
});
```

Basically the game.js shows up if I only open the index.html in a browser, but not if I do 'node server.js' and then go to localhost:1337, then it would only show the 'test' (plain text), but not the Javascript. I wasn't sure what I should have put as the title, sorry if it's misleading/makes no sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to include a static file serving middleware at the top of your stack:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
// ...
```

So if you put your js files in a subdirectory named 'public' (relative to where the script is), the browser should be able to access the javascript files.

Comment: Edited express.static to app.static but I still get this error: http://puu.sh/9JrFi/4767373cb3.png (has no method 'static')
And if I were not to edit it to that, I tried express.static and it says that express is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it but it says has no method 'static'. Here is the code: http://puu.sh/9Js1C/2cde44063d.png and here is the error: http://puu.sh/9Js4C/307a0da53a.png

Comment: No errors now, but unlimited loading time for localhost:1337 :P

Comment: Are your javascript files in the `public` folder?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? c:

Comment: Well, check your browser. What path/file is it waiting on?

Answer (score 1):

You're not configuring well express.
The static middleware handles serving up the content from a directory. In this case the 'public' directory is served up and any content (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) will be available. 
Will need the **(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));** on your express configuration

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

    app.set('PORT', 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue it was because of Express version, I upgrade it to the 4.x version, and I started to get different error (which was good) and then I used below command :

```
 app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "index.html" );
 })
```

and it worked !

Comment: what is sendFile here I am getting error like `has no method 'sendFile'`

Comment: thanks for your reply now its working fine I didn't upgraded my version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with sendfile returning the HTML but not the < script src >

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/myFile/index.html'))
```

Which was fixed by adding the static folder containing the script

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'myFile')));
```